# how to iterate json object from local storage and how to set key to another object in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have a object which is retrieved from the local storage.Now i want to iterate that object and retrieve each key and set that key to another object as an array.

I mean

```
 var a=localStorageService.get("formStructure");
    for(var obj in a)
    {
      if(a.hasOwnProperty(obj){
         //need to retrieve key value 
         form['key']=[];
    }
}
```

Now i need to iterate 'a' and assign to a another object. Output must be

```
        var form={
                   Test:[],
                   form:[]
                 }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: what's in the `a` ? can provide the data in `a`

Comment: the object is stored in locastorage so i have assigned to variable a.and now i need to iterate it and retreive key and assign it to form as an array

Comment: You put a in localstorage `{test:[], form: []}`. After that you will retrive that object from localstorage and it is the same object with array. Anyway if you get object from storage you can iterate it with `for in` `Object.keys` or get property directly `a.Test`

Comment: Yes i have tried using for ( obj in a){ if(a.hasOwnProperty(obj){
//retrieve key
})

in that if statement i am not geting how to assign the key to form as an array

Comment: i need the design of data that's in the `a` @VindyaVeer can your provide that ?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/qajeme/edit?js,console is it?

Comment: {"text":{"Name":"text","fields":[{"Name":"dfdf","type":"textbox"}],"submitlabel":"Submit","resetlabel":"Reset"},"Form 3":{"Name":"Form 3","fields":[{"Name":"Uname:","type":"textbox"},{"Name":"Password :","type":"textbox"}],"submitlabel":"Login","resetlabel":"Reset"}}

Comment: @VindyaVeer Actually while storing and retrieving  from localStorage it always does with String type. So you need to Stringify your object with JSON.stringify at the time of store, and at the time of retrieval use JSON.parse. See my answer bellow for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Stringify before need to store data on localStorage and after retrieval you need to parse it.

Look the following example.

Setting object to localStorage in normal way

```
var form={
       Test:[],
       form:[]
};
localStorage.setItem('formStructure', form);
```

Getting value from LocalStorage after normal way.

```
localStorage.getItem('formStructure');
//Output is as "[object Object]"
```

But if we Stringfy the object as JSON the then save it as follows

```
localStorage.setItem('formStructure', JSON.stringify(form));
```

Then at the time of if we parse it again we will get the proper object

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formStructure'));
```

Output as Object {Test: Array[0], form: Array[0]}. Proper object structure.

**EDIT**: For iteration of you object iterate as

```
for(var obj in a) {
    if(a.hasOwnProperty(obj)){
         form[obj]=[];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think You all dindn't understand my problem.
i have a object in a right.so now i need to retrieve keys from object and assign it to another object 'form' as a array..i mean at last of the loop i have to add property to form based on number of keys in the ' a ' object

Comment: Then provide your object structure which you are getting from localStorage. You only have provided desired output.

Comment: Use form[obj]=[]; Edited the answer also.